# Custom Validate an object Push to an array

Tags: arrays, validation, meteor, meteor-autoform, simple-schema

I am using something similar to the following schema.
By visiting the **Item** page I can add related items to the Item's **Related Items** array field.

I would like to **custom validate** the object I am **pushing** to the Item's **Related Items** field, to test if a similar object exists in the array already - so that I do not get a duplicate.

In my code below, the custom validation does not fire. I expect this may be because custom validation cannot be applied to a `type: [object]`, and should be applied to the properties of the object - but then I am unable to test the object as a whole.

```
const ItemsSchema = new SimpleSchema({
   name: {
    type: String,
    label: 'Name',
   },
   related: {
    type: [Object],
    label: 'Related Items',
    optional:true,
    custom: function () {
      let queryData = {  docId: this.docId, related: this.value }
      if (Meteor.isClient && this.isSet) {
        Meteor.call("relatedObjectIsUniqueForThisItem", queryData, 
         function (error, result) {
          if(!result){
            console.log("not unique");
            return "Invalid";
          }
          else{
            return true;
          }
        });
      }
    }

  },
  'related.$.name':{
    type: String,
    label:'Name',
  },
  'related.$.code':{
    type:String,
    label:'Code',
    min:5,
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the way to handle this.

The custom validation should not be on the [object], but rather one of the properties of the object - in this case 'source' or 'code'.

Inside one of the object properties you can call `this.siblingField(otherField);`  But it means you have to rebuild the object.

In my case :-

```
const ItemsSchema = new SimpleSchema({
   name: {
    type: String,
    label: 'Name',
   },
   related: {
    type: [Object],
    label: 'Related Items',
    optional:true,
  },
  'related.$.name':{
    type: String,
    label:'Name',
    custom: function () {

     //---------------------------
     //this is the important bit 
     //---------------------------
      let queryData = {  
           docId: this.docId, 
           related: {
              name:this.value,
              code:this.siblingField('code').value,  
            } 
      }

      //---------------------------
     //end of important bit 
     //---------------------------

      if (Meteor.isClient && this.isSet) {
        Meteor.call("relatedObjectIsUniqueForThisItem", queryData, 
         function (error, result) {
          if(!result){
            console.log("not unique");
            return "Invalid";
          }
          else{
            return true;
          }
        });
      }
    }

  },
  'related.$.code':{
    type:String,
    label:'Code',
    min:5,
  },
});
```